# Understanding Geodatabase Archiving and H tables in ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, versioning, archiving

We have ArcSDE 10.0 on MSSQL 2008 with Geodatabase archiving enabled.  In the process of updating a topology I deleted the topology, disabled archiving, unregistered as versioned and then recreated the topology.

It seems that when I did this a copy of the feature classes in the feature dataset were created at the root of the geodatabase suffixed with an "_H".  When I deleted and created the topology again the features classes were copied to the root of the gdb again with an "_H1" suffixed.

Does anyone know what's going on?  I was told these were the Archiving tables.  Please provide links if available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try disabling archiving before you delete anything. When you disable archiving, you should get a message that gives you an option to keep or discard the history (the _H table). If you keep it, then it becomes a regular ol' feature class. The _H tables track the history of changes to the default version, as you make edits to a feature class that has archiving enabled. The _H1 tables likely got created when you re-created something in the archiving enabled feature dataset.  In this case, the geodatabase first tried to create the _H table, saw that a table with that name already existed, and so added the suffix 1 to it. If you repeated the set of operations, you would end up with _H2 tables, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my first starting point:

- [understanding archiving 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/enabling_archiving.htm)
- [understanding archiving 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300001602000000)
- [understanding archiving 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geodatabase_archiving/003n000000sr000000/)

I posted all three because there is something good in each one.

Also, [here is a really old 2006 document](http://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/news/podcasts/transcripts/geodatabasearchiving_introductiontoconceptsandcapabilities.pdf) that shows not much has changed with archiving.

- [9.3 archive tables in sql server](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotNet/index.htm#geodatabases/version1743512268.htm)
- [10.0 System table in sql server](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ArcSDE_geodatabase_system_tables/002q00000080000000/)

After reading quite a bit of this.  I registered my feature dataset as versioned, disabled archiving, unregistered my dataset as versioned, and then deleted my _H historical tables.